# Sorting two lists that aren't related in Dart

Tags: sorting, dart

Suppose that I have two lists in Dart

`List a = [Instance of <Something>, Instance of <Something>, Instance of <Something> ....]`
which contains the instances of a class and `List b = [165, 75, 123 .... ]`

I want to sort `List b` in ascending order but I want the same to be reflected on `List a` as well. How do I do it?

Comment: "but I want the same to be reflected on List a as well" what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have list `a` sorted ASC/DESC to match the same sorting criteria of list `b`? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here... can you show us some of your code?

Comment: @don-prog Sorry I wasn't clear, I wanted `a` to be sorted the same way `b` is sorted.

Comment: @Balastrong Sorry for not being clear, `a` should be sorted the exact same way `b` was sorted.

Comment: Ok, than maybe julemand101 said the correct solution - use one list with your own class(or something like tuple) as item instead of two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this can be done in a more efficient way but you can do something like this. I assume the two list you want to sort has the same length.

```
class Something {
  final String name;

  Something(this.name);

  @override
  String toString() => name;
}

class Pair<T1, T2> {
  final T1 a;
  final T2 b;

  Pair(this.a, this.b);
}

void main() {
  final a = [Something('A'), Something('E'), Something('B'), Something('C')];
  final b = [1, 5, 2, 3];

  final tempList =
      List.generate(a.length, (i) => Pair(a[i], b[i]), growable: false)
        ..sort((p1, p2) => p1.b.compareTo(p2.b));

  for (var i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
    final pair = tempList[i];
    a[i] = pair.a;
    b[i] = pair.b;
  }

  print(a); // [A, B, C, E]
  print(b); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
}
```